# Compact spaces and closed sets (finite intersection property)

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am trying to prove the following theorem:

> *A topological space $X$ is compact iff for every collection $\mathscr{C}$ of closed sets in $X$ having the Finite Intersection Property (FIP) the intersection $\bigcap \mathscr{C}$ of all elements of $\mathscr{C}$ is nonempty.*

I can easily prove the forward direction but am having trouble with the reverse direction, that is "I cannot prove that $X$ is compact." I know some sort of contraposition should be used but I am not sure how. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can find a proof on [Dan's topology blog](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/11/30/the-finite-intersection-property-in-compact-spaces-and-countably-compact-spaces/).
(It was among the first hits when searching for *[compact closed finite intersection](http://www.google.com/search?q=compact+closed+finite+intersection).*)

Answer (score 26):

A topological space $X$ is compact if: for every covering of $X$ with open sets there exists a finite subcovering. You want to prove that this property is equivalent to: for every family of closed sets such that every finite subfamily has nonempty intersection then the intersection of the whole family was nonempty.

The equivalence is very simple: to pass from one statement to the other you have just to pass to the complementary of sets.

So: *open* becomes *closed*, *union* becomes *intersection*, *covering* becomes *empty intersection*. With this translation you get the desired equivalence.

Formally: Compactness means that for every family $\mathcal R$ of open sets:
$$
  \bigcup \mathcal R = X  \Longrightarrow \exists \text{finite}\ \mathcal R_0 \subset \mathcal R \colon \bigcup \mathcal R_0 = X,
$$
while the other property is that for every family $\mathcal F$ of closed sets:
$$
 \bigcap \mathcal F \neq \emptyset \Longleftarrow \forall\text{finite}\ \mathcal F_0\subset \mathcal F \colon \bigcap \mathcal F_0 \neq \emptyset.
$$

You can reverse the implication by negating both sides. Hence passing to the complementary (as said before) you get the equivalence.