# Properties of compact set: non-empty intersection of any system of closed subsets with finite intersection property

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological vector space. Let $C$ be a nonempty compact subset of $X$ and $\{C_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be a collection of closed subsets such that $C_\alpha \subset C$ for each $\alpha \in I$ with $I$ is an infinite index set. Assume that the intersection of any finite sets among $\{C_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ is nonempty. Can we conclude that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I}C_\alpha \neq \emptyset$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can. This much is true in *any* compact topological space, not only topological vector spaces

Comment: I know that, If $C$ coincides the hold space $X$ then the conclusion is YES, but when $C$ is a proper subset of $X$ I am not sure? Could you give me a short proof?

Comment: Here the compact set is $\;C\;$ , *not* the whole $\;X\;$ ...according to your question, of course.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: BTW why was this tagged ([tag:topological-vector-spaces])?

Comment: This is in fact a characterization of compact spaces, which you can find [in many places](http://www.google.com/search?q=compact+closed+%22finite+intersection%22). It is also mentioned in some posts here, for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532906/compact-spaces-and-closed-sets-finite-intersection-property

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The more general fact is true. If $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ is a collection of closed subsets with finite intersection property, then all these subsets have a common point.

Assume $\cap_{\alpha\in I}C_\alpha=\varnothing$, then for open subsets of $C$ which we denote $U_\alpha=C\setminus C_\alpha$ we have $\cup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha=C$. Since $C$ is compact, we have finite collection $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}\subset I$ such that $C=U_{\alpha_1}\cup\ldots\cup U_{\alpha_n}$. Taking complements we get that $C_{\alpha_1}\cap\ldots C_{\alpha_n}=\varnothing$. Contradiction, so $\cap_{\alpha\in I}C_\alpha\neq\varnothing$