# Decreasing sequence of compact subsets of a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $E$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $(K_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a decreasing sequence of compact subsets of $E$. Let $U \subset E$, $U$ open with $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_{n} \subset U$. Then the following assertion is true?

$$\exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}\, \text{s.t. } \forall n\geq n_{0}, \,K_{n}\subset U$$

Is there a counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that 
$$(\exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}) (\forall n\geq n_{0}) K_{n}\subset U$$
is not true.

This means that $K_n\setminus U\ne\emptyset$ for each $n$.
(Here we also use the fact that the given system is decreasing.)

Then the system $(K_n\setminus U)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is system of compact<sup>1</sup> sets which has [finite intersection property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property). By compactness we get that the intersection 
$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} (K_n\setminus U)= \left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} K_n\right)\setminus U$$ 
is non-empty.

Thus we get $\bigcap\limits_{n\mathbb N} K_n \not\subseteq U$.

This proves the claim from your question. (More precisely, we proved the [contraposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).)

---

<sup>1</sup> As pointed out in comments, this needs some clarification. Since these sets are compact, they are also closed. (This is the place where we use that we are working in a Hausdorff space.)

So we have a system of closed sets with finite intersection property. At the same time, all these sets are subsets of $K_1\setminus U$. This is a closed set of $K_1$, hence it is compact.

So we are working with a system of closed subsets of the compact space $K_1\setminus U$ which has a finite intersection property and we can use an equivalent [characterization of compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532906/compact-spaces-and-closed-sets-finite-intersection-property).

Comment: Note that the Hausdorffness is not needed.

Comment: @user87690 It is. In a countable cofinite set we can easily find counterexamples. Exercise: find the place where we used Hausdorffness....

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: It took me a couple moments to work out the non-Hausdorff counterexample.  Consider $\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology, in which every subset is compact.  Let $K_n = \{n, n+1, \dots\}$ so that $\bigcap_n K_n = \emptyset$.  Take $U = \emptyset$ which is open.  Then trivially no $K_n$ is contained in $U$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: (Replacement of a previous comment) Ah, the issue is that the finite intersection property (FIP) characterization of compactness is based on a collection of *closed* sets with the FIP (not a collection of compact sets).  Without assuming Hausdorffness, the $K_n \setminus U$ need not be closed.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed, this is what I had in mind. It's the simplest (I think) example of a decreasing sequence of compact sets with empty intersection. We really need that compact sets are closed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.　I understood.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. $K = \cap_n K_n$ is non-empty and compact (closed subset of compact $K_0$, and compact sets are closed due to Hausdorffness). We know that $K \subseteq U$. If $K_m \subset U$, by decreasingness for all $k \ge m$ also $K_k \subseteq U$. So if the statement fails we know that $K_n \setminus U$ is non-empty for all $n$.

The same fact that showed that $K$ was non-empty, shows that $\cap_n (K_n\setminus U) = (\cap_n K_n) \setminus U = K \setminus U$ is non-empty, contradicting $K \subseteq U$.