# prove finite intersection property for compact sets using sequential compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Prove finite intersection property for compact sets in metric spaces using sequential compactness with a direct proof . One approach is to prove sequential compactness and covering compactness are equivalent and then use the well-known proof for example in [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532906/compact-spaces-and-closed-sets-finite-intersection-property):
But what I want is a more direct proof using sequential compactness. 
any suggestion?
thanks in advance