# FIP and compactness

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I have been looking for a proof for the theorem

> $K \subset X$ is compact iff  every family of closed subsets of K having the FIP has a non empty intersection.

The forward direction is pretty simple the one that's causing problem is the backward direction.
I found out a couple of proof for the same but I still had some questions on those proofs.

Proof 1: [A set is compact iff all closed collections of subsets with the f.i.p. have nonempty intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823784/a-set-is-compact-iff-all-closed-collections-of-subsets-with-the-f-i-p-have-none?rq=1)

Here the question is very similar to question that I have i.e.

when we define a open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ and the corresponding compliments $\{U_\alpha^c\}$ which are closed in $X$ how can we deduce that $K \cap {U_\alpha}_i^c$ is a closed subset of K, given that backward direction doesn't make any assumption about K being closed.

The answer does address the question and invokes the definition of subspace topology to answer it, but is there a way to prove this theorem without using subspace topology or to be more precise can we deduce that $K \cap {U_\alpha}_i^c$ is a closed subset of K using only real analysis and metric spaces?

Proof 2:[Finite Intersection Property implies compactness?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507985/finite-intersection-property-implies-compactness?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The first answer makes an assertion that

> Let U be an open cover for X (which satisfies the FIP property). Then $F=\{X∖U:U∈U\}$ is a family of closed sets .

I kind of fail to understand how come $ X-U $ is closed set given that we know nothing about X being closed?

Lastly I have seen a quite a few question solving this theorem for compact space can someone explain me what's the difference compact space and a compact set.

Comment: "I kind of fail to understand how come − is closed set given that we know nothing about X being closed?": $X$ is both open and closed by definition of topology.

Comment: Compact sets and compact spaces are the same thing. It's just that when we introduce a topology we tend to call set "spaces" as we have some sort of geometrical information about them.

Comment: @sab but if we don't use that definition, is there a way to deduce the $X-U$ is closed for any X?

Comment: Is X much like $R$ in real analysis?

Comment: Sorry my comment had an error, it follows form definition of closed, not from definition of open. A closed set is the complement of an an open set. So as $U$ is open $X-U$ is closed.

Comment: "Is X much like  in real analysis?" Well this is way to general to answer as I have not clue of what you are thinking at. Which properties of $X$ are you thinking about?

Comment: You suggested that X is both open and closed , now I haven't been introduced to topology yet the theorem in question is a part of real analysis and metric spaces and the course that I'm following did expand on open and closed sets where we deduced that both R and the empty set are both open and closed.

Comment: Forget about $X$. You only have to show that closed sets the same thing as the complement of an open set (this follows directly from whatever definition you have of open set). Then you're done.

Comment: I'm kind of unclear what you are trying to suggest.I was actually looking for a proof that doesn't use topology, If K is some set in a metric space X and U is any closed set in X then $ K \cap U$ is not necessarily closed until we prove that K is closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133196/discussion-between-sab-and-grey).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and had the exact same anxiety as the OP had. But I sort out this with the following argument.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y\subset X$. Suppose $G\subset X$ is open then $G\cap Y$ is open in $(Y,d)$. Conversely, if $G_1\subset Y$ is open in $(Y,d)$, there is an open set $G\subset X$ such that $G_1=G\cap Y$.

The above argument can be proved by carefully playing around with the definitions of the metric space and the balls in the open set and it is equvilently true for closed subset. But the take-away from the argument is that any open sets in the subspace is like inherited from some open sets in the space. Back to the question, it is not hard to prove the subspace $(K,d)$ is compact by contradiction. Let $K \subset \bigcup_{G_n\in\mathscr{G}}G_n$ be an open cover of $K$ in $(X,d)$ then $K=K\cap \bigcup_{G_n\in\mathscr{G}}G_n=\bigcup_{G_n\in\mathscr{G}}K\cap G_n$. By the above argument, $K\cap G_n$ is open in $(K,d)$, then since $(K,d)$ is a compact space so there exists finite subcover $\mathscr{F}\subset\mathscr{G}$ such that $K=\bigcup_{G_n\in\mathscr{F}}K\cap G_n$ i.e. $K\subset \bigcup_{G_n\in\mathscr{F}} G_n$ and hence $K$ is a compact subset of $(X,d)$.