# Use compactness to prove that a closed bounded set of real numbers has a maximum

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

> Use compactness to prove that a closed bounded set of real number has a maximum

I met this problem when I read the introduction to point set topology in Ahlfor's book. It's convenient to solve the problem by using the closed and bounded property, since boundedness means infimum and supremum and closed means infimum and supremum are elements of the set.

I know a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ means compactness. Suppose that there's no maximum, so $\forall{x_i}\in{X}$,$\exists{x_{k}}\in{X}$,s.t.$x_{k}\gt{x_{i}}$.I want to make an open covering $\bigcup(x_i-\frac{3}{2}(x_{k}-x_i),x_i+\frac{3}{2}(x_{k}-x_i))$ of the set to show it contradictory,but I get confused of how to show it contracdictory.

Comment: Try to consider open intervals of the form $(-\infty, S-\frac{1}{n})$ where $S$ is the supremum of your set.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your hint.$\forall x{\in}X$ must be contained in $(-\infty,S-\frac{1}{n})$,and we can find "less" supremum to show it contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got part of the idea, but you need to pick your open sets to be distant from the supremum.

Let me propose, however, another argument.  For each $x\in X$, the set $X_x=X\cap [x,\infty)$ is nonempty and closed, and if you intersect finitely many of these, you obtain

$$X_{x_1}\cap X_{x_2}\cap\dots\cap X_{x_n}=X_{\max \{x_i\}}\neq \emptyset.$$

Therefore by [an equivalent formulation of compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2017601/1210477) (which I strongly encourage you to review if you are not familiar with it, as it makes life easier sometimes to think of closed sets vs open), the intersection $$Y:=\bigcap_{x\in X} X_x\subseteq X$$ is nonempty.  Let $y\in Y$, so that $y\in X$ as well.  Then $y\in X_x$ for all $x\in X$ implies $y\geq x$ for all $x\in X$, so $y$ is the maximum element of $X$.

##### Remark

If we restate the problem to prove that a compact subset has a maximum, then the statement remains true in much greater generality than just $\mathbb R$, and in fact holds if we replace $\mathbb R$ with any totally ordered set with its order topology, using the exact same proof.  (In this generality, closed and bounded need not imply compact, and in fact need not imply the existence of a maximum, so we must begin with compactness in the premise of the theorem.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have just learned that the set is compact if and only if every collection of closed sets with an empty intersection contains a finite subcollection with empty intersections, which is similar to your idea. Your proof show great generality and conciseness in some measure space, not only in $\mathbf{R}$, which I hope to learn in set point topology. By the way, I'm quite confused of your last sentence "_closed and bounded need not imply compact, and in fact need not imply the existence of a maximum_".

Comment: @KrystalJustin glad you liked it!  As for the last part, consider the totally ordered set of linear polynomials, $a+bx$, where $a+bx\leq c+dx$ iff either $a<c$ or  ($a=c$ and $b\leq d$).  Then the set $S=\{ax\mid a\in \mathbb R\}$ is open, but its complement is also open, so $S$ is closed.  $S$ is also bounded by, for example, $1$ and $-1$.  But $S$ is not compact, and you can directly see it has no maximum.  (you can imagine $x$ functioning like an "infinitesimal" that is smaller than every positive real).

Comment: In this example, is the metric space R?And how to define the distant function. I can't get it. Is $x$ for $\forall x>0$ to satify that?

Comment: @KrystalJustin no, this example is not a metric space at all, it is a general topological space, given the order topology.  If you haven't learned about general topological spaces I wouldn't worry too much about it yet, but if you want you can read about them here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology

Comment: Get it!Thanks for your patience and your answer.@MW

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there's no maximum , so $\forall x\in X$, $\exists \delta_x$, s.t. $x+\delta_x\in X$. So $X\subset \cup_{x\in X} B(x,\delta_x)$. Use compactness, we have $X\subset \cup_{i=1}^{k} B(x_i,\delta_i)$.

let $x_j+\delta_j=\max_{1\leq i\leq k}\{x_i+\delta_i\}$. But $x_j+\delta_j\in X$, this means $\exists x\in X$, s.t. $x>x_j+\delta_j$, so $X\not\subset \cup_{i=1}^{k} B(x_i,\delta_i)$. Contradiction.

Comment: We can't conclude that  $B(x_i,\delta_i)\subset X$, since we don't know that $X$ is open.

Comment: Thank you,I edit my answer, is that correct?@MW

Comment: It's a little closer to correct, but you need to pick $x_i+\delta_i$ to be the maximum out of all values of $i$, in order to get your contradiction.  Also, its a little misleading to index all of the points of $X$ with $i$, better to just choose $\delta_x$ for each $x\in X$.  Then only index your finite subcover with $i$.

Comment: Looks good now, +1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it solve my puzzle perfectly!