# Continuous Functions On A Compact Set By Means Of Metric Space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

**Question**:Every continuous function $f$ from a compact set $M$ of a metric sapce $(X,\rho)$ to the reals $R$ is bounded and attains its maximum and minimum.

**My attempts**: Firstly,I try to deal with the problem in a topological way,to show that a compact set's image under every continuous function is still compact.I prove this successfully.But I am not quite sure that continuity (topological) is as same as the continuity of metric space defined in my text book which is :$\rho(x_n,x)\to 0$ leads to $|f(x_n)-f(x)|\to 0$.And this cannot show that $f$ attains it maximum and minimum.

Therefore,I try to solve this question in another way.Since $M$ is compact and $\bigcup_{x\in M} B(x,r)$ is a cover of $M$, we can select finite of them as $\bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,r)$ and still forms a cover of $M$. If I can prove that $f$ is bounded in every $B(x_i,r)$,then I can
claim that $f$ is bounded on $M$ because $f(M)$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{i=1}^nf(B(x_i,r))$.
However,if I want to prove $f$ is bounded in every $B(x_i,r)$,it seems that I have to prove  $f$ is uniformly continuous in order to select the $r$.Up to now ,all the ways I can think about are all failed.

**Any hints or helps are appreciated!**

Comment: in topological spaces you can use the finite intersection property of compact sets https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532906/compact-spaces-and-closed-sets-finite-intersection-property

Answer (score 1):

> But I am not quite sure that continuity (topological) is as same as the continuity of metric space

It is. By definition, a map between metric spaces is continuous if it is continuous at every point, and continuity at a point $p$ is defined similarly to what you gave - except that usually one does not use sequences to define it. That is an unnecessary restriction that only works because metric spaces are first-countable (has a basis of neighborhoods at each point that is countable). The normal definition of continuity between metric spaces at a point $p$ is:

- $f:X \to Y$ is continuous at $p \in X$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in X$ with $\rho_X(x,p) < \delta$, we have $\rho_Y(f(x),f(p)) < \epsilon$.

Now the set of all $x\in X$ with $\rho_X(x,p) < \delta$ is the ball $B(p, \delta)$, and the set of $y \in Y$ with $\rho_Y(y,f(p)) < \epsilon$ is the ball $B(f(p), \epsilon)$. So we can restate the definition as

- $f:X \to Y$ is continuous at $p \in X$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in B(p, \delta)$, we have $f(x) \in B(f(p), \epsilon)$.

or more succinctly,

- $f:X \to Y$ is continuous at $p \in X$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(B(p, \delta))\subseteq B(f(p), \epsilon)$.

Now a subset of a metric space is open if and only if for each point in the set, there is a ball about it that is also in the set. Using this, we can prove that the topological definition of continuity is equivalent to the function being pointwise continuous at every point:

- If for every open set $V$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$, then $f$ is continuous at every point $p\in X$.

Let $p\in X$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. Then $V = B(f(p), \epsilon)$ is open in $Y$, and therefore $U = f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. Since $p\in U$, there must be some ball $B(p, \delta) \subseteq U$. So $$f(B(p, \delta)) \subseteq f(U) = f(f^{-1}(V)) \subseteq V = B(f(p), \epsilon).$$

- If $f$ is continuous at every point $p \in X$, then for every open set $V$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

Let $V$ be an open set of $Y$. If $f^{-1}(V)$ is empty, then it is open and we are done. Otherwise, let $p \in f^{-1}(V)$. Since $f(p) \in V$, there is some ball $B(f(p),\epsilon) \subseteq V$. Because $f$ is continuous at $p$, there is a ball $B(p, \delta)$ with $f(B(p,\delta)) \subseteq B(f(p),\epsilon)$, so $B(p,\delta) \subseteq f^{-1}(B(f(p),\epsilon) \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$.

Thus every $p \in f^{-1}(V)$ has a ball about it that is also contained in $f^{-1}(V)$. I.e., $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.